# How long can a micro SD card hold data without being powered?

Tags: memory, sd, non-volatile-memory

I lost a micro SD card few years ego, and I'm worried that someone may find it and misuse the data stored in it.

How long can a micro SD card keeps the data without being powered, ignoring other environmental factors?

Comment: Expect at least 10 years in ideal conditions (i.e. no physical damage by mechanical, chemical or electrical impact).

Comment: Until it is hit by a cosmic particle and a 1 gets changed to 0.

Comment: @SolarMike does just changing a bit makes a micro SD card undectable/unreadble by smartphones/computers? I think it may just affect a single file rather than complete SD card, unless the changed bit belongs to metadata (like magic number or something), I'm I right?

Comment: I recently found a bunch of ancient memory cards (256MB Sony M2 cards) and they were all perfectly readable.

Comment: Multi-level cells will degrade faster than single-level cells, obviously.

Comment: You can't ignore environmental factors. It depends on brand/quality/specifications, type and size of flash cells, and how worn out the flash cells were when you lost it. If it is in a cool place it might last for tens of years. If in a hot place maybe less. And data blocks are stored with ECC so it is protected from random failures and worn out flash cells. And someone might have found it already and copied all data for later use.

Comment: @DamienD, not surprising.  The main cause of data loss is charge leakage; ancient memory cards will use very large memory cells that store a lot of charge.

Comment: I recently found in a cupboard 6 Compact Flash cards with camera photo files from 2002 to 2004, and I was able to copy them all.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to use the data on an SD card, assume it lasts less than 10 years. (*)

If you don't want someone else to be able to read the data on an SD card, assume it lasts indefinitely.

If bits gets flipped through cosmic rays passing through it, it depends where the bits are that get flipped. If they are in insignificant data bytes in a file, then the file will appear damaged, but readable. If they are in a FAT, then some files may be lost, at least to normal attempts to read it.

It depends what level of adversary you are facing, a casual nosy person or motivated agency-backed hackers. The nosy person may well see your data, the hackers certainly will. If the adversary does a low level dump, then the slightly damaged files will be still be there.

(*) You know you don't really *have* data unless you have three copies of it, don't you? On at least two different types of media. With at least one stored off site. This is the 321 of data backup.

Comment: Data on SD cards is not just stored as-is, it is protected with ECC. Few flipped bits here and there is not a problem, as error correction will repair data errors that are within limits. Only when enough bits within a block has flipped, the data cannot be recovered any more, and user will get a read error.

Comment: Don't flash cells lose data due to leakage, not cosmic rays?

Comment: @forest Yes leakage is usually the main loss mechanism in commercial NAND storage, and especially at high temperature retention of cheap storage can be quite limited. Unfortunately this is old (pre-3D NAND), but has some info:  https://www.virtium.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/WP22-1120-01-Impact-of-Temperature-on-SSD-Data-Retention.pdf

Answer (score 4):

SD cards and other solid-state storage lose data primarily through charge leakage, where electrons spontaneously migrate out of the storage cells.  The leakage rate [depends strongly on temperature](https://www.jedec.org/sites/default/files/Alvin_Cox%20%5BCompatibility%20Mode%5D_0.pdf), both the temperature of the card when it was written and the temperature where it is stored.  If you wrote data on the card at the North Pole and then dropped it in the middle of the Sahara Desert, the data's probably long gone; if you went the other way around, it's probably all still there.

The actual situation is probably somewhere in between.  If you were to find the card tomorrow, you'd probably be able to read almost all of it, but a small amount of the data will have been corrupted through charge leakage.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should be worried.

IF they find it, if they try to read it, then they may get your data.

If they find it, and then just format it to test it then they won't get your data.

Consider protecting data - passwords etc in the future.